# Why does JSLint return an Unexpected 'String' message?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've wanted to add some additional functionality to strings in Javascript and am using the following JavaScript code:

```
String.prototype.left = function (n) {
    "use strict";
    return this.substring(0, n);
}

String.prototype.right = function (n) {
    "use strict";
    return this.substring(this.length - n); 
}
```

However, when I run this code against JSLint, I get the following error: Unexpected 'String'.  I'm not quite sure what the error means, and I don't know if I should be changing something in my JSLint settings to "avoid" the error or if I should change my code.

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of your first `}`

Comment: Pretty bad error message for missing semicolons.

Comment: I feel like there was some speech where Douglas Crawford expressed unwillingness to make error message easy for programmers to understand... oh right that's every speech :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using semicolons, I get no errors/warnings with this:

```
String.prototype.left = function (n) {
    "use strict";
    return this.substring(0, n);
};

String.prototype.right = function (n) {
    "use strict";
    return this.substring(this.length - n); // <-- SPACE HERE
};
```

After adding in the semicolons, it warned me about an unexpected Space character where I added the comment above. So remove that space (and my comment) and it should validate fine there.

Comment: Ah, the semi-colons!  Thank you so much.  Funny how you miss the simple things after staring at it for too long.

Comment: @QuittersNL Haha no problem. Yeah, it's a weird error message for that problem, but in a way, it makes sense. Anyways, glad it's working for you now :)